# authenticate my TF code with my vault server

Tags: terraform, vault

I am new to vault and I would like to do something really simple. I would like to inject my vault `username` and `password` in my TF codes so Vault can authenticate my credentials during my app boostrap. Normally this is how I authenticate with my vault locally:

```
export VAULT_ADDR=https://myvault.dev
export VAULT_SKIP_VERIFY=true
export VAULT_NAMESPACE=myns
vault login -namespace=myns -method=userpass username=myuser password=mypwd
```

Now I am using a user data script I am injecting in my TF code during boostrap to access vault and get my secret :

`main.tf`

```
resource "aws_instance" "myec2" {
   ami = "ami-082b5a644766e0e6f"
   instance_type = "t2.micro"
}


  user_data = <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x -v

exec > >(tee -i user-data.log 2>/dev/console) 2>&1

# Install latest AWS cli
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install --update

# Install VAULT cli 
sudo wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/1.8.2/vault_1.8.2_linux_amd64.zip
sudo unzip vault_1.8.2_linux_amd64.zip 
sudo mv vault /usr/local/bin/vault
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/vault
vault -v

# vault env var
export VAULT_ADDR=https://myvault.dev
export VAULT_SKIP_VERIFY=true
export VAULT_NAMESPACE=myns

# Return only my secret key:
vault kv get -field=pass secret/myscret
```

Now I am not sure how to log in to vault from inside my app before getting my secret. The key thing is that I do not want to hard code my vault credentials in my TF code since I will push my code to a git repo. I would appreciate any help. Let me know if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

As your application are inside ec2, you may enable aws auth method in vault and use ec2 method instead of your credential to login

Document: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/aws

Comment: thanks for the reply but I am still not able to authenticate with my vault from within the app. I might have to find a different path.